# How does merge work within eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, github, merge

Perhaps I am looking in the wrong places, but can anyone explain how "Team >> Merge" works within Eclipse?  I ended up with instances of git comments interjecting into my code throughout the project, and would like to not have to delete my branch and rebuild.

Example:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
    static final void method(String input) {
=======
    static final void method(String input, int i) {
>>>>>>> master
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your git found a conflict there. You have now both version in your code HEAD and master. You should check which version you want to keep, and remove manually the the rest.

Just literally delete the `<<<<<< HEAD` stuff, till you only see `static final void method(String input) {`.
Since I'm working with Android, I didn't use Eclipse in years, but there should be a way to use a GUI for git, so you don't have to delete those lines manually.

Comment: At the time, I had several files that I reformatted with a multitude of actual, functional changes. There must've been a thousand of those injections into my code, so I sanely scrapped it - I did a no-no and saved a copy of my entire directory to work in changes later.

At a later date, I was able to test it out when there were only thirty or so.  I appreciate the time you took to ensure I didn't go crazy - even if I took a while to get back to you.